# Are all versions of Jonas part of the same loop?

Tags: dark

In the season 2 finale of [*Dark*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_(TV_series)) (Netflix), there are two versions of Jonas from the future: the young Jonas and the older Jonas (also known as Stranger). After seeing the episode, it seems to me, that the young Jonas is more informed than the older Jonas.

For example, the older Jonas tries to save Martha by locking her into the bunker. Later, we see young Jonas trying to save Martha unsuccessfully, as she is killed by Adam. Although I can understand that the older Jonas would probably try to save Martha anyway despite knowing what will happen (because he has seen her dying when being the young Jonas), knowing what he knows, he should probably try to stop Adam from shooting Martha, or approach saving Martha in a better way. (Guarding the bunker if he suspects she will leave anyway, etc.)

Another strange coincidence along these lines is the business of starting/ending the wormhole passage. At the end of season 1, the older Jonas uses the time machine to break the passage between 1953, 1986 and 2019. He claims he is doing this to prevent all the problems with the time travelling. To that, Noah notes that Jonas is simply being manipulated. But at the end of the season 2, the young Jonas does exactly the opposite: he uses the time machine to start the passage together with Claudia.

While we can still imagine that the older Jonas simply changed his mind and decided to close the gate later, it can also hint that the older Jonas is less informed than the younger Jonas - possibly not being the same person, but maybe person from alternate reality.

**Are younger Jonas from the future and older Jonas from the future the same person, or are they two persons from alternate realities?** (Does the older Jonas have all the memories of the young Jonas?) Are there other indication to support / oppose the claim?

Comment: The big reveal at the end of S2 definitely opens the possibility of the Stranger being an entirely different Jonas. Also, +1 for more Dark questions. More questions means more chances of people watching this excellent show.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Spoilers for Season 3]

Since this question was written before season 3, I'll just address the question of whether the middle-aged "Stranger" Jonas is the future self of the teenage Jonas we see in seasons 1 and 2, leaving aside the issue of the multiple versions of teenage Jonas created by the "loophole" in season 3.

I don't think there's proof in the show either way about whether there actually are "cycles" where things may change subtly from one cycle to the next, or whether there's just a fixed 4-dimensional structure of events (the [block universe](https://www.abc.net.au/news/science/2018-09-02/block-universe-theory-time-past-present-future-travel/10178386) view). But I prefer to interpret the story in terms of the second perspective (see my answer [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/234238/22250) for some reasons), meaning that Stranger Jonas is just the older self of teenage Jonas, and I don't think your examples really provide evidence against this perspective. I'll address your second example first:

> While we can still imagine that the older Jonas simply changed his mind and decided to close the gate later, it can also hint that the older Jonas is less informed than the younger Jonas

The show actually does make pretty clear that there's no conflict in motives here, young Jonas explicitly says that the reason he's messing with yellow waste barrels (adding some dark matter to them, it seems) and re-opening the cave passage is out of hope that he can change things in a subtle way, so that when *he* gets older and tries to close the gate, he will succeed in destroying it rather than just temporarily shutting it for 33 years. He was led to believe this by old Claudia, who he had spent some 12 months with, learning about time travel, after his failed attempt to stop his father's suicide. About 6 minutes into episode 8 of season 2, here's his dialogue with middle-aged Claudia, telling her about the ideas he got from old Claudia:

> Jonas: My future self tried to shut the hole. To reverse it all. The passage was closed, but the cycle wasn't broken. But **you said** that we could change one factor in the equation so that he...So I'd be successful the next time. Then none of this sick shit will ever happen. Mikkel won't vanish. Michael won't hang himself. Your father won't die.
>
> (he walks up the yellow waste barrels)
>
> The big things and the little things don't follow the same rules. We won't be able to change the grand scheme of things...(he opens a barrel, and unscrews one of the dark matter canisters from the time machine) but the details. We change a grain of sand, and with that, the whole world.

Then a little after 15 minutes in, there's this dialogue:

> Claudia: What is this?
>
> Jonas: The passage. We are reopening it.
>
> Claudia: But you said you wanted to shut it. In the future. Or the past, your future.
>
> Jonas: It took me a long time to accept that I had to help start the disaster I wanted to avert.
>
> Claudia: How do you know all this?
>
> Jonas: The past 12 months. You taught me everything, about the future and the past. Everything that has happened. Everything that will happen.

In season 3 episode 6, middle-aged Claudia encounters teenage Jonas in the post-apocalyptic era for the first time, and shows him that the portable time machine she'd been using (the one created by Tannhaus) was broken, so their only hope is to work on getting the "God Particle" time portal working. At around 26 minutes in she is seen encouraging Jonas in the view that the dark matter he added to the cave at the end of season 2 had changed the "variables" so that he might succeed in destroying the cave passage even though he remembered his older self failing:

> Claudia: It doesn’t work. (referring to the portable time machine) Maybe this is how it had to happen first. For things to change next time. The substance in the apparatus. You and I brought it into the passage again. The variables in the equation were changed. There’s a chance it might work next try.

At this point Jonas resists the idea:

> Jonas: I can’t wait 33 years to try! I’m supposed to just hope this won’t happen again? Maybe next time I’m on the other side of the bunker door?

Then in a scene starting about 16 minutes into episode 7, we see Jonas attempting suicide but repeatedly failing (Noah cutting him down from the rope, and his gun continually jamming), so I think this is the point when he accepts that there are no shortcuts and he really will have to work on getting the God Particle time portal functioning for the next 33 years, but holds on to the strand of hope Claudia gave him, that when he finally does go back he'll be able to destroy the cave passage.

Later in episode 7, we see that Stranger Jonas still has the same hope in a scene set in 2040. His comments to Noah just a little under 27 minutes in:

> Everything repeats itself. If I travel back, I know I can change everything. My older self tried it before. But this time it's different. The components in the passage have changed. This time it'll work.

Noah infers that Claudia gave him this idea, and tells him not to trust her. And in fact, we had earlier confirmation that Claudia was indeed manipulating Jonas into thinking he could succeed at permanently closing the passage when she knew it wouldn't work; the reason she lied to him was that Jonas' attempts to change things by closing and re-opening the passage were key to ensuring the passage would exist in the first place. Go back to the scene in episode 5 of season 3, about 20 minutes in, where the middle-aged alt-Claudia from Eva's world is talking to the the middle-aged Claudia from Adam's world (this is shortly before she finds teenage Jonas in the post-apocalyptic era). Here, the middle-aged Claudia directly paraphrases the statement from teenage Jonas I quoted at the beginning, the claim "The big things and the little things don't follow the same rules. We won't be able to change the grand scheme of things...but the details. We change a grain of sand, and with that, the whole world." And alt-Claudia tells Claudia that Jonas only believed this because her older self had told him that as part of her attempt to manipulate him:

> alt-Claudia: I know you thought you could trust him, but you can't do that.
>
> Claudia: Who?
>
> alt-Claudia: Jonas. He belongs to the dark.
>
> Claudia: Jonas? He's dead.
>
> alt-Claudia: No. He's not. He wants to destroy both worlds forever and untie the knot. He doesn't know that death is what he'll want in the end. But all his impulses on this journey will lead to that end. But Eva wants to save both worlds.
>
> Claudia: I don't understand. **Jonas said we could change it. We change one component, we change the entire world.**
>
> alt-Claudia: **It was you who told him that. Your older self.** A positive feedback loop. Jonas opened the passage in 2020. The older Jonas had previously shut it in 2019. After it'd been opened in the summer of 1986 for the first time. In all three moments, they left behind traces of cesium residue, a component of the black matter.
>
> Claudia: Half-lives.
>
> alt-Claudia: In every cycle, at each of these three moments, this cesium is carried through the tunnel and back before it's completely decayed. It exponentially expands endlessly.
>
> Claudia: So the passage is the result.
>
> alt-Claudia: **It must continue to exist forever. Everything has to happen again. Jonas has to bring the matter to the passage.** And opening one of the nuclear plant barrels has to trigger the apocalypse. Everything in this loop repeats. Life...and death.

Later, around 55 minutes into episode 7, we see a scene set in 2052 where the time portal in the wrecked nuclear plant is finally working, and old Claudia continues to encourage Stranger Jonas in the idea that "this time" will be different for him:

> Claudia: The matter, it can finally be stabilized. But everything must happen again, exactly the same way. You have to lead your younger self down the same path. He must not act differently. You have to set the course, no matter how hard it may seem. But you’ll finally be able to change everything. The apparatus. He will repair it. (she gives Stranger Jonas a copy of Tannhaus' book *A Journey Through Time*) You must destroy the passage, and the knot with it. This time you’ll get it. (he starts to leave) Jonas. You must never give up hope.

Now, going back to your first example:

> For example, the older Jonas tries to save Martha by locking her into the bunker. Later, we see young Jonas trying to save Martha unsuccessfully, as she is killed by Adam. Although I can understand that the older Jonas would probably try to save Martha anyway despite knowing what will happen (because he has seen her dying when being the young Jonas), knowing what he knows, he should probably try to stop Adam from shooting Martha, or approach saving Martha in a better way. (Guarding the bunker if he suspects she will leave anyway, etc.)

I think that Stranger Jonas' plan is to wait for Adam to appear at the house during the apocalypse as he remembered him doing, and shoot him, with Martha off in the bunker so there's not a danger Adam will kill her first, or that she'll be caught in the crossfire. Look at the scene about 36 minutes into episode 8 of season 2, which starts with Stranger Jonas staring at the gun on the table. Then teenage Noah comes in (having been sent by Adam from 1921 to 2020 earlier in the episode), they have a little dialogue:

> Jonas: Noah.
>
> Noah: You look different now. You know, I mean, since last time.
>
> Jonas: He sent you, didn't he? Adam.
>
> Noah: I've always wondered when you turn into him.
>
> Jonas: I won't. I will never do the things he did.
>
> Noah: He said you'd say that kind of thing. He also said we'd be friends. Before I'm betrayed.
>
> Jonas: Why do you follow him?
>
> Noah: What made you follow her? Claudia. We both want to believe. We fasten ourselves to the salvation that's promised. (approaching Jonas, who points the gun at him) **If you kill him...you kill all hope of salvation.** (Noah puts his hand on the gun) He is the savior. (he gently pushes the gun away) You'll be the savior. (he pulls out the letter from alt-Martha that we learn more about in season 3)
>
> Jonas: What is that?
>
> Noah: Read it. It's from Martha.
>
> Jonas: (reading) This can't be real.
>
> Noah: You must save her. Bartosz, Magnus and Franziska. And later, me and Agnes. This circuit has to be finished for the next cycle to begin. Just as the prophecy foretells. And so that Martha can live.

It's not definitive, but the part in bold (combined with Jonas staring at the gun while sitting in the same room where Adam killed Martha) is what makes me think his original plan was to wait for Adam to arrive and kill him. If you take the official website as canonical, the [section on The Stranger](https://dark.netflix.io/en/event-timeline/the-stranger) indicates this as well, swipe through the different events in his life until you get to the screen titled "Martha's Letter" where the text says "Jonas waits with a gun for Adam as the apocalypse approaches. He wants to kill him before Adam gets a chance to shoot Martha."

Then it seems that the letter from Martha (which we later learn was from alt-Martha, and dictated to her by her older self as part of a plan to manipulate Jonas) changed his mind, causing him to go find Bartosz, Magnus and Franziska and save them from the apocalypse (accidentally taking them all to 1888), as Noah said he must do. Here's the text of the letter, revealed a little under 2 minutes into episode 6 of season 3, with the key line that may have changed Jonas' mind in bold:

> Dear Jonas,
>
> You promised to make everything right again. I want you to know that you will do that. You must never lose hope that there is a way out of this maze. A way to save me and you. But we will have to make sacrifices...do unimaginable things...to untie the knot at the end. Each fate in this knot is linked to the next. A thread, blood-red, that connects all our actions. In light and in shadow. But the apocalypse must take place. **You must let me die, so I can live. We have to let some things go before they find their way back to us.**
>
> You and I are perfect for each other. Never believe anything else.
>
> Martha

Answer (score 2):

[Spoilers for Season 3]

There are 2 versions of Jonas: Young Jonas and The Stranger. The thing is,

> The Stranger later becomes Adam

These two versions exist because of an event that happens right after Martha has been killed by Adam. Warning! Spoilers ahead.

> 1) Martha from the Alternate World/Eva's World (lets call her Martha B) visits Jonas(lets call him Jonas A) and escorts him to Eva's World. Eva's World is almost similar to Jonas' World but there are a few differences. The biggest one is that there's no Jonas, because in that world, Mikkel doesn't travel back in time, and hence Hannah never marries Mikkel/Michael and gives birth to Jonas. Therefore Young Martha from Eva's World(lets call her Martha A) doesn't know who Jonas was at first but Jonas manages to convince her that he's from another world and he needs her help. Eventually they falls in love and have sex. Martha A gets pregnant. However, long story short, Jonas A is killed by a future version of Martha. Remember, Martha from Jonas' World is already dead. we get to see 4 different versions of Marthas at the same place,but they are the same Alt Martha from different points of her timeline. So Jonas A's journey ends after he gets Martha A pregnant and is killed by a future version of the same Martha.

> 2) Martha from Alternate World doesn't visit Jonas. Jonas, under the instructions of the Stranger, manages to escape the Apocalypse by going inside the bunker. Then he graduallly transforms into The Stranger we frequently see in S01 and S02, learning more about time travel and Adam's plans. He then eventually travels back into the time where Apocalypse happens and tries to save Original Martha, alongside Young versions of Magnus, Franziska and Bartosz. However Original Martha gets killed by Adam. Meanwhile, The Stranger manages to save Magnus,Franziska and Bartosz by escorting them to 1880s. There, he tries to create a time machine like the one he had seen when he had travelled to the future (2053). His idealogies and thoughts change over the time he obsessively tries to build the machine, and eventually transforms to Adam.

Comment: There are 3 versions of Jonas.  They all stem from Martha being shot: 1 version ran down the stairs into the basement.  This is the version that goes on to become The Stranger and then Adam.  The second version is saved by AltMartha, this version impregnates AltMartha and then is promptly killed because he is in the wrong timeline.  The final version is saved by Adam, this is the one that is sent to rescue pregnant altMartha and they time travel to the origin world.  All that being said, all versions of Jonas comes from 1 timeline, the Adam timeline.